# How to debug onDelete authentication trigger in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I wonder if I can somehow debug Firebase onDelete trigger from authentication module. I need to test my function which is triggered on User deletion. Can I do it locally? Uploading that function every change is very burdensome.

Comment: The documentation for local testing is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Answer (score 0):

One solution for that is to change `onDelete` hook to http request and use this as regular endpoint.